# google analytics - allowed domains

Tags: google-analytics

My GA tracking code is being referenced on another persons website.  I am currently tracking several domains/sub-domains in one profile.  Is there a way to create a list of allowed domains for reporting and data collection purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Go in to Google Analytics, at the bottom click on Filter Manager.  Add a new filter, with the type "Exclude all traffic from a domain" and enter the other person's domain name.  Select your website profile and save.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm concerned about having to modify the filter if this happens with another site referencing my tracking code.  Since our domains aren't going to change, I thought an allowed list would be more efficient.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this.  It's sort of crazy that people are stealing your javascript tracking code though...  never had that happen.

Comment: I think you should take advantage of the situation and sell them the data back...  ;-)

Comment: It's very random, some remote city in Texas used it on a few of their sites.  Maybe they copied some code from me?

Comment: Have you tried to low-tech option. Write them an email and ask them to remove the code?

Answer (score 0):

Could be they have a similar account number and haven't realized that they are using yours instead. Boy, hope they're not getting paid for analytics by a client. That would be most embarrassing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an Include filter instead of an Exclude filter.

Create a regexp with all the domain and sub domain names on which you run your UA number :

```
^www.domain1.com|^www.domain2.com$
```

This way you are sure to only get your data.

If you use e-Commerce transactions, they cannot be filtered out by hostname: you need to setup a filter on the transaction ID, matching the format of your transaction IDs.